# Find the highest common factor.

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Find the highest common factor h of 366 and 305. 
Find s, t ∈ Z such that
h = 366s + 305t.

I think i have to go through Euclid's algorithm to find h, then backtracking gives you s,t. but not sure how to implement the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$366=2\cdot 3\cdot 61$$
and $$305=5\cdot 61$$

Comment: +1. This is all OP needs in order to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called the extended euclidean algorithm that is used to calculate these numbers. However, one can figure $s$ and $t$ from the usual euclidean algorithm as well. In your example using the euclidean algorithm we get that 
$$ 366 = 305 +61$$
$$ 305 = 5\times61$$
So we see that $h=61$ and so rearranging the first equation gives us $s=1$, $t=-1$. More generally if we are given two numbers $a,b$ the euclidean algorithm gives us a bunch of equations 
$$ a=q_1b+r_1$$
$$ b=q_2r_1 +r_2$$
$$ r_1 = q_3r_2 + r_3$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$ r_n = q_{n+2}r_{n+1}$$
Where $r_{n+1}$ is then the GCD. To figure out $s$ and $t$, we back track.  Multiplying the first equation by $q_2$ and then using the second equation gives us that
$$q_2a = (q_2q_1+1)b -r_2$$
we then repeat until we get an expression in terms of a,b and $r_{n+1}$ and this will give us $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard layout for the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which relies on the fact that all intermediate remainders are linear combinations of the given numbers. In addition, if you proceed one step further, you write $0$ as such a linear combination, i.e. you obtain the l.c.m.
$$\begin{array}[t]{l@{\qquad}rrrr}
\text{Successive Divisions}& r_i & u_i & v_i & q_i\\
     \hline
 & 366 & 1 &0 & \\
366 = {\color{red}1} \times 305 +\color{blue}{61} & 305 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{1} \\
\hline
    305 = {\color{red}5} \times 61 + \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{61} & 1 & -1 & \color{red}5 \\
     & \color{blue}{0} & -5 & 6 \\
     \hline
    \end{array}$$
Thus we have
$$\gcd(366,305)=61=1\cdot 366-1\cdot305,\quad\operatorname{lcm}(366,305)=5\cdot366=6\cdot305$$